# How to handle 'Interaction Not Found' error for CreateFolderAdapter function with dynamic UUID appendage?

Tags: javascript, go, testing, components

How can I mock the UUID generation for the CreateFolderAdapter function, where the generated UUID is dynamically appended to a path, while encountering an "Interaction Not Found" error for the mocked CreateFolder operation?

When attempting to mock the create-folder API for QuickSight,we are passing the unique-id for folder and this is expected to be dynamically generated.
input:

```golang
createFolderInput := &quicksight.CreateFolderInput{
   AwsAccountId: aws.String("Account_id"),
   FolderId:     aws.String(uuid.New().String()),
   FolderType:   aws.String("SHARED"),
   Name:         aws.String("Folder-Name")
}
```

This input is sent as param to  `svc.CreateFolder(createFolderInput)`, where 'CreateFolder' is aws-sdk.Internally this uses folder-id to formulate the path:`HTTPPath:   "/accounts/{AwsAccountId}/folders/{FolderId}"`.
While performing component-testing, the mock creates new path every time it is executed.
sample interaction code:

```
createInteraction('Create Folder API Interaction', createRequest('POST', '/accounts/{accountId}/folders/11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555 ))
handler.addInteractionHandler(interaction.flow, (ctx) => {
 return {
  flow: interaction.flow,
  strict: false,
  request: {
  method: interaction.request.method,
  path: interaction.request.path,
    body: ctx.data.body,
  },
  response: {
    status: ctx.data.status,
    body: ctx.data.response,
  }}})
```

This doesnt match interaction as path path created might be : `/accounts/{aacountId}/folders/f7eacb57-a3fe-4786-b376-44d2cf458fa7`
What is the way to handle dynamic paths for interaction?